# Height/width animation in Android Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, animation, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'd like to know, is it possible to make height/width animation for View in Visual Studio Xamarin? For example, when a user clicks on a button the height of a view changes.

I looked for solution on the Internet, but only found Xamarin.Forms solution, but I need solution not for XamarinForms. Using scaleY is not a solution.

Comment: So not Xamarin forms, but Xamarin Android (Native)?

Comment: To @Digitalsa1nt Exactly

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus where did you find the solution for Xamarin.Forms. It would be great if you can provide a link.

Comment: @Anoop , I didn't work with Forms, only with native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I have found solution. We have to use ValueAnimator.

```
clickedButton.Click += (s,e) =>{
    int viewHeight = animatedView.Height;
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.OfInt(viewHeight, 0);
    animator.SetDuration(500);
    animator.Update += (object sender, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e) =>
    {
        var value = (int)animator.AnimatedValue;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = animatedView.LayoutParameters;
        layoutParams.Height = value;
        animatedView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
    };
    animator.Start();
}
```

Or we can create function for collapse/expand animation

```
ValueAnimator animateCollapse(int from, int to, int duration, View animatedView)
{
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.OfInt(from, to);
    animator.SetDuration(duration);
    animator.Update += (object sender, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e) =>
    {
        var value = (int)animator.AnimatedValue;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = animatedView.LayoutParameters;
        layoutParams.Height = value;
        animatedView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
    };
    return animator;
}
clickedButton.Click += (s,e) =>{
    ValueAnimator animator;
    if (isExpanded){
        isExpanded = false;
        animator = animateCollapse(originalHeight, 0, 500, animatedView);
    }
    else{
        isExpanded = true;
        animator = animateCollapse(0, originalHeight, 500, animatedView);
    }
    animator.Start();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Exactly what I was looking for too.